# Chrony 506 Cannot talk to daemon

Tags: ntp, chrony

I'm having trouble configuring chrony to sync the time between my raspberry pi and a desktop computer in an isolated network.

My raspberry pi's chrony.config file looks like this:

```
server master
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
logdir /var/log/chrony
log tracking measurements statistics
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
commandkey 1
local stratum 10
initstepslew 20 master
allow 192.168.3.136
```

The master's chrony.config file, which is the desktop, looks like this:

```
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
commandkey 1
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
initstepslew 10 192.168.3.155 192.168.3.135
local stratum 8
manual
allow 192.168.3
```

The master is able to connect, but every time I try to run chronyc tracking on the raspberry pi it says '506 Cannot talk to daemon'.

I have another desktop computer that's also trying to act as a client, and it has the same problem.

What additional information can I provide to help people debug my problem? Unfortunately I don't even know where to start, and I haven't found anything useful on Google.

Comment: [cross-post](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/11875/)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue. The problem was that "master" in the slave's .config file was referencing the name of the computer. If you read http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/manual.html#server-directive, you'll see that the server "directive is immediately followed by either the name of the server, or its IP address." Since my computer wasn't actually named "master," I was supposed to use the computer's IP address. This fix allowed me to correctly sync my computers with Chrony.